# Filtering Condition in n-Table Joins

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We seem to have a need for a multi-table JOIN operation and I am referring to some notes from an RDBMS class that I took several years ago.  In this class the instructor graphically depicted the structure of a generic N-table JOIN query.

[image]

The figure seems to conform to examples of multi-table JOINs that I have seen but I have a question.  Does the WHERE clause, for providing filtering, necessarily have to be the last clause in the query?  Intuitively it appears that we can impose filtering conditions before a following JOIN clause, in order to properly scope the data, before we input it to the next JOIN operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Aside from JD's Answer, ...)

SQL syntax is picky; `WHERE` comes after all the `JOINs`.

The `ON` clauses *should* say how the table is 'related' to the preceding table.  Otherwise, it works identically to `WHERE`.

I'll quibble with the "notoriously inefficient".  This depends on the `ONs` and `WHERE`.  In particular, if `WHERE` filters on more than one table, the Optimizer must *guess* at what order to look at the tables, and may fail to do the best job.  Also, it implies gathering data from some tables for throwing out the rows due to a `WHERE` clause that is acted on later.

The Optimizer is free to look at the tables in any order and rearrange `ON` and `WHERE` clauses *as long as it leads to the same resultset*.

An optimization that shows up some times:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM a
    JOIN b  ON b.x = a.y
    WHERE b.x = 123
```

The Optimizer is smart enough to realize that `a.y` is necessarily filtered to "123".  This might be advantageous, for example, if `a` has `INDEX(y)`.

After `WHERE` can come `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, `ORDER BY`, and `LIMIT`, each optional, but necessarily in that order.

`HAVING` is identical to `WHERE` *but* `HAVING` can see aggregates, but `WHERE` cannot.  Example:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS ct
    FROM t
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING ct >= 2
```

This provides any users that show up at least twice.  This cannot be done with `WHERE`.  (OK, you could do it less efficiently via a subquery with `WHERE`.)

Answer (score 1):

Within the same single query, the `WHERE` clause always syntactically proceeds all `JOIN` clauses. Your observations are correct that *filtering* can occur both in the `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses and that functional commonality between them is called a **predicate**.

A **predicate** is a logical expression / condition that evaluates to a boolean value, and hence is how filtering can be applied to the `JOIN` and `WHERE` (and even the `HAVING`) clause.

The reasoning the `WHERE` clause can only be applied *near* the end  is because of logical syntax within the query language to define different purposes (elaborated in the next paragraph) and partly due to the way the predicates are applied are different for the `WHERE` clause vs the `JOIN` clause. This article gives a brief overview of the [order of operations in MySQL](https://www.eversql.com/sql-order-of-operations-sql-query-order-of-execution/) (which is generally true for most modern RDBMS). The 5 second version is the `JOIN` operations are generally applied first, then the `WHERE` operation happens after, except in cases when the optimizer realizes it's more efficient to utilize the predicate of the where first.

The `WHERE` clause directly filters the entire joined dataset effectively, where the predicates of `JOIN` clauses *can* affect either the entire dataset (indirectly) or only that output of the two tables being joined (directly).

Comment: This is only for the syntactic element. The actual order that the predicates are checked during query execution may be different - and WHERE predicates may be checked before the ON predicates.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Do you have documentation to back that up?...thinking about it from my own knowledge, I believe what you're saying is correct actually, but also invalidates what my linked resource states. I do see Rick James's answer where there can be a little *cheating* by the optimizer so long as the results are guaranteed to be the same.

Comment: Even your linked article states: **`In many cases though, the database's optimizer will choose to evaluate the WHERE part first, to see which part of the working set can be left out (preferably using indexes), so it won't inflate the data set too much if it doesn't really have to.`**

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Fair enough. That verbiage is a little generalized and contradicts their opening statement unfortunately, but I'm with ya. Thanks! I'll update my answer accordingly.